# how to loop a for loop 5 times that is already looping a python code in subprocess?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, subprocess

code:

```py
    import subprocess
    import json


    my_dict = {}
    for i in range(10):
     x=subprocess.Popen(["python","first.py"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = x.communicate()
        my_dict.update({i: json.loads(output[0])})
```

This code loops a python script for 10 times and saves the output in a dictionary.

How to loop this for loop  5 times so that there will be two for loops.

Comment: Do you want to update this dict only all 5 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a loop outside this, if you want to update the same dict.

```py
    import subprocess
    import json


    my_dict = {}
    for j in range(5):
        for i in range(j*10, j*10 + 10):
            x=subprocess.Popen(["python","first.py"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            output = x.communicate()
            my_dict.update({i: json.loads(output[0])})
```

Explanation of - `range(j*10, j*10 + 10)`
It basically changes the range of dict according to different loop so that values don't get overriden and dict gets extended accordingly with changing loop. 
Previously, It was updating the same `10 indices` of dict.

I hope it helps.

Comment: `my_dict = {}
    for j in range(2):
        for i in range(2):
            x=subprocess.Popen(["python","first.py"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            output = x.communicate()
            my_dict.update({i: json.loads(output[0])})`  tried running with 2,2.  expected output is 4 but only 2 is in dictionary

Comment: need to append all the loops data. i think it is overwriting in j loop

Comment: I have made the changes. Please check it.

Comment: its working, can you elaborate a little more about this.  `for i in range(j*10, j*10 + 10):`  explain a bit

Comment: Updated the Explanation in answer.